# Ruby's capybara-webkit installer cannot build native extension

Tags: ruby, webkit, installation, capybara

When trying to install capybara-webkit

```
gem install capybara-webkit
```

I get this error:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit: 
>    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.4.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.4.1/./gem_make.out

I'm on Windows 7 64bit and I'm installing it so I can use the compressor script bundled with Blueprint CSS.

I had no issues until now (everything was pretty clear even when JSON needed Devkit to be installed, or when I had to install the bundler gem to get the `bundle install` working), and this is just where I am stuck.

Comment: Have you had issues installing/building gems in the past on this particular machine/server?

Comment: Hi normalocity, this is my first experience with Ruby, I'm installing it so I can use the compressor script bundled with Blueprint CSS. I had no special issue 'til now (everything was pretty clear even when json needed Devkit to be installed, or when I had to install the bundler gem to get the "bundle install" working), and this is just where I am stuck becouse no other seem to have my issue...

Comment: These sorts of errors can be gem specific in some cases. Since it's failing on the native extension portion, the first place I would check is to make sure that you have any necessary compiler(s) installed in order to build the native code. Check the docs for capybara-webkit and see if they have custom instructions for installing/building on Windows.

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of "gem_make.out" (the log file mentioned on the last line of your console output)?

Comment: Looks like one person had a similar issue (maybe related, maybe not) here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/6

Make sure you have the "rake" gem installed and let me know.

Comment: Just installed rake but same error... and, if it can help, the same error happens also in a Windows 7 32bit environment: wow! I can try version 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.2 (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), I'll let you know!

Comment: Same error with 1.8.7 version, both in W7 32 and 64bit, and with "rake" gem installed previously :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al last I didn't solve the capybara-webkit installation, but a simple use of "bundle install --without test" did what I was trying to do (and what was my last aim): use the Blueprint CSS compressor script

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when running

```
bundle install
```

with a Gemfile that contained capybara-webkit. I ran

```
bundle install --without test
```

instead and this worked. Maybe not applicable but perhaps for someone who encounters this issue from bundling.

Comment: That was probably because capybara-webkit was declared under the the test group in the gemfile. So doing `bundle install --without test` did not installed any gems declared there.

Comment: What to do if I can't simply skip the test section and NEED capybara-webkit to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me om OS X yosemite

```
brew link --force qt5
```